# Inconsistent Folder redirection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection

Operating on a 2008R2/Win7 Domain:

We are using folder redirection with VM desktops for the users to create a roaming profile of sorts, without actually using the roaming profile.

Folder redirection is applied VIA user GPO. Problem is under certain circumstances we have to delete out old user folders. When this happens sometimes everything works flawlessly and new folders are created/redirected, other times new local user profiles are generated but remote files are not created.

Have tried several different fix's involving clearing out old user data from the registry, clearing out local profile data completely. Sometimes this works 5 times in a row, and then suddenly it stops working altogether for a while. The inconsistency is hat is really getting us. Any Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Folder Redirection != Roaming Profiles. You can't "sort of, kind of" have roaming profiles if you're only using Folder Redirection. Why are you deleting "old" user folders? What are these "old" folders? Are you deleting the parent redirected folder or the contents of the redirected folder?

Comment: Correct, Folder redirection is not Roaming profiles. Unfortunately Myself and my fellow admin's do not have control of that part of the system design, This is what was given to us to make work, and we have to do what we can to make it work :\

We are deleting the root user folder user.name, And all sub folders. As to why, it is another "this is something that has to happen in our envirnment and as stupid as it is, we are bound by it" things. There is no *real* reason

Comment: Is your redirection policy set to move or copy? Or do you mean you're deleting the user folders on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being someone that has been known to work in environments with stupid requirements I have sympathy and one suggestion.  Can you add a login script that looks for the redirected folder and creates it if it doesn't exist?  That way, by the time the user is fully logged in the folders are guaranteed to exist and hopefully you won't have the local creation problem.

Comment: That is what we ended up going with. Thanks for taking the time to reply, much appreciated. :)